# How to define a function in the Node.js prompt, without the dot prefix?

Tags: javascript, node.js, read-eval-print-loop

Using the `defineCommand` we can define a command  that can be invoked using a dot before it:

```
replServer.defineCommand("foo", ...)
```

Then, in the repl, we can do:

```
> .foo
```

And that will call the command we have defined.

I would like to replicate the same functionality like in the nodejs debugger to define the commands like functions, instead of using `.keyword`.

Using `useGlobal: true`, we can pass the `global` context to the REPL, and then access any global functions, but I am wondering if there is a way to add them automatically in the REPL help output, like the `defineCommand` does.

How can we do that?

Here is a sample from the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl_replserver_definecommand_keyword_cmd).

```
const repl = require('repl');

const replServer = repl.start({ prompt: '> ' });
replServer.defineCommand('sayhello', {
  help: 'Say hello',
  action(name) {
    this.clearBufferedCommand();
    console.log(`Hello, ${name}!`);
    this.displayPrompt();
  }
});
replServer.defineCommand('saybye', function saybye() {
  console.log('Goodbye!');
  this.close();
});
```

---

This is how the help output looks like:

```
$ node tmp.js                                                                                                                                                      
42                                                                                                                                                                                                          
> .help                                                                                                                                                                                                     
.break      Sometimes you get stuck, this gets you out
.clear      Break, and also clear the local context                 
.editor     Enter editor mode
.exit       Exit the repl
.help       Print this help message
.load       Load JS from a file into the REPL session
.save       Save all evaluated commands in this REPL session to a file
.saybye
.sayhello   Say hello
$ node debug tmp.js
...
debug> help
run, restart, r       Run the application or reconnect
kill                  Kill a running application or disconnect

cont, c               Resume execution
next, n               Continue to next line in current file
step, s               Step into, potentially entering a function
out, o                Step out, leaving the current function
backtrace, bt         Print the current backtrace
...
```

Comment: Did you solve the issue? I am looking for the same solution

Comment: @Sisir I didn't actually solve this, but it should be possible by creating globals...